# Speed run of Black Temple: Which bosses to kill?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

In preperation for Cataclysm, our guild is attempting to start work on obtaining legendaries from Classic and The Burning Crusade. This means, in part, doing a run at Illidian as often as we can pull one off.

Having never raided in The Burning Crusade, I'm a bit unclear as to what bosses we have to kill to get to Illidian. From a brief glance at the map on Wowhead, it looks like we can skip most of the instance, going directly from the entrance, to [Supremus](http://www.wowhead.com/zone=3959/black-temple), then to the Den of Mortal Delights, killing [Mother Shahraz](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=22947) and the [Illidari Council](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=23426), then heading to the Temple Summit to kill Illidian.

Is this right? Or is there a portal / door somewhere that doesn't open until we've killed all the additional bosses as well? For example, in ICC, it is impossible to kill the LK without killing the end-wing bosses. (And it was similarly true in Naxx before that.)

Any advice on this front is welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You won't be able to skip any bosses in Black Temple. Well, maybe Na'jentus, but I've never tried, and honestly, he'll take you 30 seconds, as killing him would not require clearing any trash that you wouldn't need to clear just to get to Supremus.

The door to the Den of Mortal Delights will not open until Teron Gorefiend, the Shade of Akama, Gurtogg Bloodboil, and the Reliquary of Souls have all been defeated. Once you've defeated those, the door to Sharhaz's area unlocks, and it's a linear run upstairs, and Mother and the Council will both obstruct you unless killed.

Answer (score 0):

Now when Demon Hunters are live it works to skip a few bosses when you play as one. After you've killed the first 2 bosses when you go into the big hall. Go straight to the left and climb the chain (very easy with double jump). After that you just jump over to the balcony with Fel Rush. When that's done you just skipped 4 bosses.

Comment: It could be possible to do with other classes too if you use goblin gliders ect.

Comment: So which bosses do you have to kill?  Just linking a video doesn't really answer the question, since if the video goes down, your answer is no longer valid.

Comment: I edited the post if it was misleading to anyone I am sorry.